# OperationalError at / no such column: app_post.category_id

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project (like a blog), and I'm bit struggling with when I edit models in live project (meaning that I cannot lose my db).

In this case originally I didn't have category to my posts, now I have added but there is an issue.

When I apply makemigrations and migrate, I get this:

> OperationalError at /
>
> no such column: learning_app_post.category_id

Tried also this by some internet sources: `python manage.py migrate --fake learning_app zero`

... and when I `migrate` again, I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "learning_app_post" already exists`. So I end up in the loop, any ideas here?

This is my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Category name")
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def clean(self):
        if self.parent:
            if self.parent.parent:
                raise ValidationError("A category that already has a parent cannot be set as the parent of another category.")
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['category_name']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    ... #rest of the post model
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did `makemigrations` succeed (create a migrations file)?  If so, does that migrations file look correct?

Comment: Yes, `makemigrations` have succeeded and file looks correct.

Comment: When you run makemigrations, is that specific migration file the one that causes the error?  Or is the error on a different migration file?

Comment: In the end I solved problem by deleting data base and populated data manually because I had to move with development. But I'm going to have to solve this problem for future because deleting database tomorrow wont be possible. Answer to your question; No error was caused by makemigrations and I had deleted all migrations files so it would be only one without errors.